# 413 Request Entity Too Large using laravel and amazon S3

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, amazon-s3

I trying to upload GIF using laravel file uploader.

but not able to upload on the server and getting below issue

```
   413 Request Entity Too Large
```

Below is code which I did

```
  $extension = pathinfo($i->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $filename = time()."_image.".$extension;
  $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
  $filePath = '/foldername/' . $filename;
  $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($i), 'public');
```

Below details, I changed

```
post_max_size 128M
upload_max_filesize 100M
memory_limit 256M
```

also changed the config in apache file still not working

System Information

```
OS:- Ubuntu 16.04
PHP Version:- 7.1
File manager:- Amazon S3
```